# ClaimsCurrent.Principal sometimes doesn't return HttpContext.User

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, owin, claims-based-identity

We use ASP.NET MVC 5 with the OWIN Cookie Authentication to provide Claims-based identities. All of this works fine. User logs in, an identity is created and returned as a cookie, future requests have custom validation logic to ensure that cookie remains valid and updates the identity on an as-needed basis.

The problem is that very intermittently (once or twice a day, every couple of days) a single request will fail part way through when trying to access the identity via `ClaimsPrincipal.Current`.

The frustrating thing is that ALL of these failures are within actions that have authorization attributes on them. So all of the failure occur **after** the cookie has been validated and the OWIN cookie middleware has set the identity into the request context (and thread).

Even more baffling is that in some cases a method that utilizes `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` to get a particular claim will execute correctly and then later in the request another method may fail to find the same claim.

Where is my identity going?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this issue? I'm experiencing the same thing. Not much info about it out there on the net either.

Comment: Nope. It's a weird problem and has basically caused trust issues between me and any static context within any framework. Within the structure of ASP.NET, always try to use the local `HttpContext` object provided by the controller or filter arguments. Design your code and services to require situational context (like current user) as an argument for methods. Don't use or trust "ambient" context.